# Дизайн тени в Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Помогите как добавить полупрозрачный градиент или тень как на картинке, это можно сделать как то со скриптом или только картинку так нарисовать ?...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

моя кнопка для которой нужна тень с полупрозрачным градиентом ниже -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: всё зависит от целей и что это в целом такое.... если UI кнопка - то проще картинкой, если 3D кнопка - можно шейдер сделать,  а может она входит в группу нескольких объектов с тенью, то может надо разместить источник света где-либо..... и вдобавок от того, если это всегда статичная тень - то запечь тень......

Comment: я добавил картинку с кнопкой, вот часто нужно добавлять тень для таких елементов и что бы выгледело как градиент но как решить ...

Comment: Открываешь Asset store и ищешь, столько вариантов... А вообще у UI canvas  есть 2 эффекта, но помогут ли он тебе( Shadow и Outline)

Comment: @Xumera_hZ на сторе смотрел и про дефолтные варианты тоже в курсе... поэтому и спросил здесь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению только этот эффект `Shadow` можно использовать для тени в Юнити, решил вопрос простой картинко...